# Failing (exit status 66) to download Golang packages in a windows based Docker container

Tags: docker, go, docker-for-windows

Forgive me if this is a duplicate as I have not encountered a similar issue on stackoverflow before.
Kindly provide the link if you have one.

**The issue:**

I have downloaded several Windows Golang images from docker hub and I have tried installing  (go get) packages from inside the container. 
This fails with the following error (happens for all the various images I have tried).

[image]

I have even tried using a pure [windowsservercore](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/) image, where I installed Golang and Git before running the go get command.

I’m not entirely sure what the issue could be but I believe status 66 has something to do with data race ? how do I fix this ?

**Reproducing:**

Step 1:

```
Docker pull golang:1.11.1-windowsservercore-1709
```

Step 2:

```
Docker run -it --rm golang:1.11.1-windowsservercore-1709 powershell
```

Step 3:

```
PS C:\gopath> go get -d github.com/gorilla/mux
```

**Screenshot of a failed docker build.** 
[image]

Comment: I ran : docker run --pull -it --rm golang:1.11.1-windowsservercore-1709
Then when in the container i checked that the go environment variable was there
and checked that git was installed.
Finally ran the go get github.com/gorilla/mux and all was cloned fine.

Comment: Hey @leeroya thanks for the quick response. I have tried your suggestion but somehow it does not work on my machine. Please see the image attached.

Comment: I managed to have a look at this, so it turns out that you do not have PowerShell available to you in this image. Not all windows images come with Powershell only CMD, so change the Dockerfile to call the CMD like this:               RUN ["CMD", "-c", "go get -d github.com/gorilla/mux"]

Comment: I ran into the same issue (though with a different go package). Although certainly, powershell is available on my docker, the tip which @leeroya gave directed me to a good workaround. Changing: RUN powershell go get github.com/... to RUN cmd go get github.com/... solved it. Apparently it is powershell in the container which affects 'go get' somehow.

Comment: Honestly it worked for me too. @Leeroya please put your response in the answer section so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to have a look at this, so it turns out that you do not have PowerShell available to you in this image.

Not all windows images come with Powershell only CMD, so change the Dockerfile to call the CMD like this:

`enter code here`RUN ["CMD", "-c", "go get -d github.com/gorilla/mux"]